# Laravel - selectRaw( count(*) ) is returning as string and not integer?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, highcharts

I don't know how this happened. Because in my `localhost`, it is properly working, but after in my shared-hosting, then I noticed it. The reason I'm going to convert to int is because of the highcharts. https://www.highcharts.com/errors/14

**code:**

```
public function assistance()
    {
        $programs = DB::table('assistances')->selectRaw('services.name, count(*) as y')
        ->join('services', 'assistances.service_id', '=', 'services.id')
        ->groupBy('service_id')->get();

        return $programs;
    }
```

The **JSON output** is this:

```
[
   {
      name: "BMAP", 
      y: "1"
   }
]
```

it should be `y: 1` without the quote.

What is missing? Is this a server issue?

Comment: Did your query is correct ? join after select not causing any problem ?

Comment: @SagarGautam i guess so because in my local, it is 100% working.This the is the JSON output from localhost `[
{
"name": "BMAP",
"y": 153
},
{
"name": "HOPE Scholar",
"y": 126
},
{
"name": "Logistics",
"y": 150
},
{
"name": "Youth",
"y": 126
},
{
"name": "Others",
"y": 125
}
]`

Comment: Place your join clause before selectRaw it may work

Comment: check this [JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#example-4418) this will convert string to number in back end side itself

Comment: This is a known bug in certain PHP versions. PHP 5.3.3 even added a flag `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`.  What is the PHP version in production vs local?

Comment: @Pablo Production: **PHP 7.1.12** (cli) (built: Dec  4 2017 08:21:16) ( NTS ). Localhost: PHP **7.0.13** (cli) (built: Nov  8 2016 13:45:28) ( ZTS )

Answer (score 3):

I'm using MySql and had success converting the result in the query. It's a little less smelly than the json_decode and json_encode solution.

```
    ->selectRaw('services.name, CAST(count(*) AS UNSIGNED) as y')
```

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer using JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK reference from the comment of @Deep3015.

**Solution** : json_encode() and json_decode();

```
public function assistance()
    {
        $programs = DB::table('assistances')
        ->join('services', 'assistances.service_id', '=', 'services.id')
        ->selectRaw('services.name, count(*) as y')
        ->groupBy('assistances.service_id')->get();

        return Response::json(json_decode(json_encode($programs, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)));
    }
```

Comment: Is `toJson()` available to `$programs`? See https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_toJson